# Remembering checkbox values when updating form

Tags: php

I have the below code and I am trying to retrieve data already posted when 
updating the form but I can't just get my code to work. The ELSE part works just fine but the first condition is not working.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  if((strtoupper($sub1_name) == 'Art') || 
     (strtoupper($sub2_name) == 'Art')){
       echo 'checked';
       }
}else{
  echo (isset($_POST['subject2'])?'checked="checked"':'');
  }
```

Comment: The condition make no sense. You are checking GET when on else POST and on GET value you check some totally unrelated variable

Answer (score 0):

`strtoupper` returns a string where all the characters are uppercase, so it can never be equal to a string that contains a mix of upper and lower case characters. It should be:

```
  if((strtoupper($sub1_name) == 'ART') || 
     (strtoupper($sub2_name) == 'ART')){
```

Comment: Thanks very much! What a silly oversight on my part!!